# ListBoxFor returns null values when submitting the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with the ListBoxFor... It works fine by the Get request, it loads the list and pre-selects the selected values but when the user edits the form and submits the page, it returns null; it does not return the selected values... Can anyone help? I'm very new to programming in general and I can't figure this out.
This is my ProjectDetailsViewModel:

```
public class ProjectDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string ReturnMessage { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
        public List<ProjSubIndustryMaster> SubIndustries { get; set; }
        public List<ProjIndustryMaster> Industries { get; set; }
        public List<Potential> Potentials { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectCategoryMaster> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectResources> ProjectManagers { get; set; }


        public List<ProjectResources> SalesManagers { get; set; }

        public List<ProjectOriginationMaster> OriginationList { get; set; }
        public List<MasterProject> MasterProjects { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectStatusMaster> ProjectStatusList { get; set; }
        public List<PrimaryMaterials> PrimaryMaterialList { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectMaterialMaster> MaterialList { get; set; }
        public List<PrimaryServices> PrimaryServiceList { get; set; }
        public List<ServiceCodeMaster> ServiceList { get; set; }
        public List<PrimarySources> PrimarySourceList { get; set; }
        public List<SourceCodeMaster> SourceList { get; set; }
        public List<ProjTechnologyTypeMaster> TechnologyTypesList { get; set; }
        public List<PrimaryTargets> PrimarytargetList { get; set; }
        public List<TargetCodeMaster> TargetCodeList { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectTypeMaster> ProjectTypesList { get; set; }
        public List<ProjectComment> Comments { get;set; }


        public List<string> SelectedServices
        {
            get
            {
                var serviceList1 = Project?.ProjectPricings?.Where(x => x.ProjectId == Project.Id && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ServiceCode))
                        .Select(x => x.ServiceCode)
                        .ToList();
                var serviceList2 = Project?.Services?.Select(x => x.ProjServiceCode).ToList();
                var serviceList = new List<string>();
                if (serviceList1 != null) serviceList.AddRange(serviceList1);
                if (serviceList2 != null) serviceList.AddRange(serviceList2);
                return serviceList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

just for clarity purposes: I'm loading the listBox with data taken from a Master(look-up)table so the user can have "all" the options available to choose from for example: ProjectMaterialMaster table which has 2 columns- Id and Material... In other words, the selected values are not taken from the same table as the data from the listBox. The tables look like this:

```
    ProjectMaterialMasterId  MaterialCode
      1                          A
      2                          C
    ...
     ProjectMaterialId      ProjectId     MaterialCode
        1                     4118            C
        2                     5342            C
        3                     5647            A
        4                     4118            B
 ...
```

The 1st table has all the materials available and the second table is a mapping table and connects all the projects to their associated material...

This is my View:

```
<td class="control-input">
            @{
                var materials = Model.Project?.Materials.Select(x=>x.ProjMaterialCode);
            }
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => materials, new MultiSelectList(Model.MaterialList, "ProjMaterialCode", "ProjMaterialCode", materials), new {@class = "listbox"})
        </td>
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateProjectView( ProjectDetailsViewModel projectViewModel)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = @"Error! Update Failed.";
                return GetProjectView(projectViewModel.ReturnMessage, projectViewModel.Project.Id);
            }
            if (projectViewModel.Project.Id != null)
            {
                var success = ProjectDataAccess.UpdateProject(projectViewModel.Project);
                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = success ? @"Project Updated Successfully" : @"Error! Update Failed";
            }
            else if(projectViewModel.Project.Id == null)
            {
                var success = ProjectDataAccess.AddProject(projectViewModel.Project);
                projectViewModel.ReturnMessage = success ? @"Project Added Successfully" : @"Error! Insert Failed";
            }
            return GetProjectView(projectViewModel.ReturnMessage, projectViewModel.Project.Id);
        }
```

Comment: Because you creating a `<select>` with a `name` attribute that has no relationship to your model - your model does not contain a property named `materials`. Use a view model that contains a property `IEnumerable<string> Materials` to bind to, and a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MaterialsList` for the options.

Answer (score 0):

```
m => materials
```

should be

```
m => m.materials
```

Comment: As you can see on the code "materials" is a variable that I stuffed  in var materials = Model.Project?.Materials.Select(x=>x.ProjMaterialCode);

Comment: This doesn't work, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You need to refer directly to the model property. You may need to rework your ViewModel

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I tried many ways already and I can't figure it out. I'm very new to all of this. Thanks.

Comment: can you not reference the property directly in the listboxFor? As in m=>m.ProjMaterialCode?

Comment: no because ProjMaterialCode is not a property from the ViewModel directly, it is a property from the ProjectMaterial table and The Project table has a list of ProjectMaterials as one of it's properties and the View Model has a List of Projects....